# “Histogram and binning” technique for categorical variables publication and implementations

Tags: random-forest, decision-tree, h2o, categorical-data

H2O.ai have implemented the "histogram and binning" technique for efficient and accurate tree-building using categorical variables of high cardinality (>100): http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/gbm-faq/histograms_and_binning.html

Somewhere in their documentation, they have a reference to a publication that details the method but I can't seem to find it anymore - can anyone link to that publication?

Given that the method, which seems to be state-of-the-art for tree-building using categorical variables, is published - are there really no other implementations than H2O.ai?

In sklearn, this feature has been brewing for years on github but apparently still hasn't come out.

I asked the question previously on Data Science: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/40241/histogram-and-binning-technique-for-categorical-variables-publication-and-impl

Comment: do you have any recollection of what version of documentation you were looking at when you found a link? another suggestion would be to read through the gbm booklet: http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/booklets/GBMBooklet.pdf

Comment: @Lauren Thank you for the booklet, good to read through. I found the link in the documentation last July/August and couldn't find it anymore in October when I came back to my problem dataset...